# Excel - Condition based calculated average of networkdays

Tags: excel, vba

I have three columns in excel displaying Solved(1,0), Start date and Lastchanged date.
The columns I am speaking of is read from a sql database.
I am having trouble making a formula that gives the average of networkdays where solved=1 in excel. Help?

Comment: have you looked at the worksheet formula Workday?

Comment: what do you mean when you say "average of networkdays"? Do you mean you want the average difference between LastChanged Date and Start Date for all the rows Solved = 1?

Comment: I have had no luck producing an average of workdays or networkdays on the two ranges where the condition is Solved=1 .
I am stuck.

Comment: @Jaycal Correct, but networkdays will provide workdays instead of actual days

Answer (score 0):

Easiest Method:

In cell D1 type "Difference".

In cell D2, type

```
=(C2-B2)
```

to get the difference in days between the two dates. Drag this down for the length of the two columns.

Highlight the column headings A1:D1 and then click Sort & Filter -> Filter.

Now click the dropdown in column 1 and uncheck "0". Only records with a 1 will be left.

Then go to the bottom of your columns and in the first empty cell in column D, type:

```
=average(D2:D...)
```

and for the "..." enter the last cell in the D column where you have a number. Then just press enter.

Comment: Thanks, But filters and new columns will not be "maintainance free"
Because the sheet loads new values from sql database each 10th minute.
I use a different sheet to show live statistics of the day.

Comment: You might want to include that information in your original post so people can post appropriate suggestions.

Comment: Sorry, it is my first post here.
I see that I only included:
"The columns I am speaking of is read from a sql database"
I will explain better if I post a question again.

Answer (score 0):

`NETWORKDAYS` function doesn't accept a range as start date or end date but in Excel 2007 or later it accept "arrays" so an array formula like this will average the number of workdays between cols A and B where col A = 1

`=AVERAGE(IF(A2:A10=1,NETWORKDAYS(B2:B10+0,C2:C10+0)))`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

The +0 converts a range like `B2:B10` to an array that `NETWORKDAYS` can handle. Because of those +0s you can only have numeric values (like dates) in B2:C10

Comment: Thanks, :)
Very close.
 
`=AVERAGE(IF(A1:A?=1,NETWORKDAYS(B2:B?+0,C2:C?+0)))`
Is there a way to fill in the questionmark based on countrows or something?

Comment: There shouldn't be a problem using a range larger than needed - blank rows will be ignored so you can use a large range like A2:A1000 - alternatively you can use INDEX like `A2:INDEX(A2:A1000,COUNT(A2:A1000))`.....or you can use a "dynamic named range"

Answer (score 0):

I guess the function `INDIRECT` may help in combination with `=AVERAGE(IF(A1:A?=1,NETWORKDAYS(B2:B?+0,C2:C?+0)))`. From Excel Help: "[The INDIRECT function] Returns the reference specified by a text string. References are immediately evaluated to display their contents. Use INDIRECT when you want to change the reference to a cell within a formula without changing the formula itself."

In addition (this is not specifically answering your question, but you may find it useful), the function `SUBTOTAL` can give you the average among only displayed cells (i.e., not hidden or filtered). Thus, you may apply a filter to see the average you are looking for.